# ProgressBar with Gtkmm in c++

Tags: c++, c, gtkmm, gtkmm3

Hello I know how to create a progressBar with Gtkmm. I know also with a button how when I click on the button the progressBar increase of 10% for instance. But I don't know how to implement a progressBar which increase automatically I mean like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++){

        double percentage(progressBar.get_fraction() + 0.1);
        progressBar.set_fraction(percentage);
        getchar();
}
```

But I don't see when the progressBar increases... I just see when the progressBAr is full...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: C is not C++. Please don't spam with unrelated language tags.

Comment: How many threads do you use? Is this loop executed in the main thread that is also responsible for UI updates?

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: @Gerhardh  At stackoverflow, they don't care that c and c++ are two different languages. So stop spamming that c and c++ are not the same. :P  I tried to remove tags that referenced c and c++ at the same time, but I was stopped by moderators who don't know squat.  As is their wont!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a progress bar (or spinner, etc.) that should actually change its appearance, you need to ensure that the main thread gets some time to update the UI accordingly.

If you have a loop in main thread that sets new values and blocks the thread in `getchar()`, this thread cannot update the UI to reflect the new state of any widget.

To see your updates you should move the loop calling `getchar` in some other thread and only do the `gtk_*` function call in the main thread. This can be achieved by enqueing an update-function via `g_idle_add()`.

Then the UI can be updated while your thread is blocked.

If you replace `getchar` by some other action that takes some time, this other activity will also prevent the thread from updating the UI unless you move it in some other thread.

You might also think about other mechanisms to return control back to the main thread between updating the widget's state.